Applied Multivariate statistical Methods
I want to refer and practice exercises in applied multivariate statistical methods for an upcoming exam. Please share any good reference material that I can work out and refer for practice. I have the book by Richard A. Johnson.
Currently, I am looking for something to work out and practice exercises and numericals and try out all the methods outlined for this subject.
Topics to include: Total Least Squares, Principal Components Regression, Partial Least Squares, Non-negative matrix factorisation, Anova, Manova, Functional PCA

Multilevel analysis is different. I have removed that tag.
